# Function declaration instead of comment

Tags: linux, comments, kernel

I noticed that in the Linux kernel 2.4 file sched.c there's a line that says:

```
void scheduling_functions_start_here(void) { }
```

and one that says

```
void scheduling_functions_end_here(void) { }
```

Shouldn't this kind of stuff be written as a comment? What is the gain of using functions?

Comment: Maybe something uses pointers to those functions to figure out which block of memory contains all the scheduling functions.. I have no idea if that's true, just a thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I just did some googling, and can now somewhat back up my comment. 
Check out [process.c](http://www.google.co.uk/codesearch/p?hl=en#KVTjzuVpblQ/pub/linux/kernel/v2.4/linux-2.4.16.tar.bz2|IBjatzNgisc/linux/arch/alpha/kernel/process.c&q=scheduling_functions_start_here), line 439 onwards.

I don't read C too well, but it looks like it needs to check whether a thread is in a scheduling function or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Linux kernel author, but the most likely answer is that function names are more likely to appear in an IDE's file index than comments are.